# Excel VBA method range of object _worksheet failed ERROR

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, compiler-errors

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

curRow = 1
Dim maxRow As Integer
Dim copySuburb As String


myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse Workbook")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
wb.Activate

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.Range("BB:AX, AV:AR, AQ:AL, AA:AK, X:W, U:T, N:O, L:B").Delete

ws.Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
ws.Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
ws.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

maxRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ws.Rows(maxRow).EntireRow.Delete
ws.Rows(maxRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete
ws.Rows(maxRow - 2).EntireRow.Delete

maxRow = ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Count

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A1:I" & Rows.Count)
        .Header = xlNo
        .Apply
    End With
    

Do Until ws.Range("A" & curRow).Value = vbNullString

ws.Rows(curRow + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

ws.Range("C" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("D" & curRow - 1).Value

curRow = curRow + 2

Loop



End Sub
```

Here is my code. My question is I get an error on the line where it says `ws.Range("C" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("D" & curRow - 1).Value`

All I needed to do is to copy the value of the cell located in column D to C (different rows). I browsed the internet of what caused this error, I suspect that the worksheet I am currently on is not the active one? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If `CurRow = 1`, then `ws.Range("D" & curRow - 1)` will not have any meaning for row 0 (zero)... That's why the error. No matter  if the worksheet is active or not, since it is fully qualified.

Comment: omg thanks! didnt realise that

Comment: Glad I could help! I would transform the comment in an answer, but it is a too simple observation... :) Instead of `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort` you should use `ws.Sort`, since it is qualified. And, in order to be able to run the code, even if another sheet would be the active one, use `ws.Range("A1:A" &...` or `ws.Range("B1:B" &...`.